# Entity Framework - Include Take Top N for each parent

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am implementing a forum where each post can have comments.

I want to load a batch of N posts so each post loads the first K comments.

I've got this code to start with, but it currently includes **all** the comments with each post. **How do I only load first K comments with each post** without having to make K calls to the database?

```
List<ForumPost> result = ctx
                            .ForumPosts
                            .Include("Comments") // <-- ??? How to take first K ???
                            .Where(i => i.Thread.ID == threadID)
                            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
                            .Take(N).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Currently, in EF you cannot filter or limit the `Include`d related entities in any way)*. It's possible in EF Core since 5.0: [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include).

If you need to avoid the multiple queries, there are solutions, but they all involve working directly on the SQL side. You can use: TVF (table valued functions), stored procedures, views, or a simple query. In each case there are different solutions to map the results to your entities. And the mapped entities will be non-trackable, so that you cannot modify and write them back to the server (unless you add them explicitly to an existing `DbContext`)

You can read this article by Julie Lerman to see what I'm speaking about: [Use Projections and a Repository to Fake a Filtered Eager Load](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/use-projections-and-a-repository-to-fake-a-filtered-eager-load/).

You can vote for a related feature at [Data User's voice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions). Look for "Allow filtering for Include extension method". Most probably, if this is implemented, it will also be possible to use `.Take` in this situation.

For more information on the evolution of this feature, take a look at [EF Core github issue 1833: Support filtered Include](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833). There you can find interesting things like:

- EF 6: [EF Plus IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)
- EF 6: [Dynamic global filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters)
- EF Core: [Model-level entity type filters](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/commit/b1379b10fba013bcb70b60250e39eae8e895a6c3)

Comment: Yes thanks, I voted for that one.

Comment: @Paceman looks like the solution from the link works for your case (which I believe involves ***one-to-many*** relationship). What I tested involves ***many-to-many*** relationship and it did not work.

Comment: Anything new in EF Core?

Answer (score 3):

I think `Include` currently does not have that filter feature. You can try using explicit loading instead. However with this way the query does not look nice, I would use a `foreach` after you have a List of `ForumPost`:

```
List<ForumPost> result = ctx
                        .ForumPosts                            
                        .Where(i => i.Thread.ID == threadID)
                        .OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
                        .Take(N).ToList();
//start loading top K comments from each post
foreach(var post in result){
    ctx.Entry<ForumPost>(post).Collection("Comments")
                              .Query()
                              .Take(k);//assume k is a constant
}
```

**Edit**: (to make it work with one round trip to db)

The duplicate question has an answer about this but it's not working if the relationship is ***many-to-many***, at least that's from what I tested in **EF6**. For ***many-to-many*** relationships, I tried finding a solution and ended up with the following code which works BUT there may be some trade-off on client side where you need a loop to reset all RelationshipEntries' State to `Unchanged` to mimic that they all are loaded from database.

```
ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var stateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var result = ctx.ForumPosts.Where(i => i.Thread.ID == threadID)
                .Select(e => new { e, Comments = e.Comments.Take(k) })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(e => {
                   //set the Comments manually
                   e.e.Comments = e.Comments;
                   //Reset RelationshipEntries' state
                   foreach(var c in e.Comments) {
                      stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(e.e, c, o => o.Comments, 
                                                           EntityState.Unchanged);
                   }
                   return e.e;
                }).ToList();
```

The loaded result is even cached into Local. Now it does just one round trip to db (right after calling `AsEnumerable()`).

Comment: This is one way but it still uses multiple DB calls doesn't it? I was hoping that there was a way to avoid N calls to the database by using some linq syntax that would use witchcraft to translate it into a single SQL statement.

Comment: @Paceman yes, you're right, it requires multiple round trips to db. But as I said there is currently no way to use `Include` as what you want. I'm however not so sure about that, let's see if some others could give some suggestion.